# Put html code in StringObject.replace()

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have this code:

```
return stringObj.replace(/\040&\040/, "<span style=\"font-size: 80%\"> & </span>");
```

And it's adding `<span style=\"font-size: 80%\"> & </span>` into the DOM as text. How can I add it as HTML?

This is my full code:

```
function replaceText(text) {
        var stringObj = new String(text);

        stringObj = stringObj.replace(/\040&\040/, "<span style=\"font-size: 80%\"> & </span>");
        return stringObj.replace(/\040([ąćęóńłżź\d\w]{1,2}){1}\040/gi, ' $1_');
    }

var node = document.getElementById('some_id');
node.textContent = replaceText(node.textContent);
```

Before I can see: Hey Monik & Ann
After replace on my page shows up not "small AND" but "small end" with html code eg:
Before: "Hey Monik & Ann"
After: "`Hey Monik<span style=\"font-size: 80%\"> & </span>Ann`"

Why browser can parse my html code?

Comment: how are you creating the html? Are you using the DHTML DOM to change the text of an element, or the element itself ?

Comment: No I have static html document and I want replace Char "&"(Amp) to small amp with font size 80%

Comment: what do you mean by "like text", "like html"?

Comment: can you post all the funtion until displaying in browser ?
did you use .innerHTML ?

Comment: fixed some grammar to better explain the situation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `textContent`

> The **textContent** property **sets or returns** the **textual content** of the
>   specified node, and all its descendants.

So as per your problem,browser is considering **span** as a **text** and **not an html element**

> To **set or return** the **HTML content** of an element, use the **innerHTML**
>   property.

So your code should go like this:

```
var node = document.getElementById('some_id');
node.innerHTML=replaceText(node.textContent);
```

Comment: No, because regular expression is working. But on my screen i can see html source like "<span style="font-size: 80%">&</span>", so browser seees it as plain text.

Comment: how you are inserting it back to html??more code needed.